# Different log level for different classes

Tags: java, log4j, logback, slf4j

Below, I have a logback configuration that is applied globally.

I would like to make the logging level ERROR globally, except for one class. For one specific class, I want to make the logging level INFO. How can I do that?

```
<configuration scan="truef" scanPeriod="30 seconds">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="com.foo.web.online.util.log.LogMaskingPatternLayout">

                <pattern>[START] Date: %d{yyyy-MM-dd} | Time: %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} | Level: %-5level | Logger: %logger{5} | Marker: %marker | CIP: %X{clientIp} | UserAgent: %X{userAgent} | Website: %X{website} | SID: %X{sessionId} | RID: %X{requestId} | CID: %X{conversationId} | TID: %X{transactionId} | App: %X{app} | SubApp: %X{subApp} |  Msg: %msg [END] %n</pattern>
                </layout>     
            </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="SIFT_INFO" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.JNDIBasedContextDiscriminator">
            <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="FILE-${contextName}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
                <file>/opt/local/logs/online/${contextName}.log</file>
                <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                    <fileNamePattern>/opt/local/logs/online/${contextName}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
                    <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
                </rollingPolicy>
                <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
                    <layout class="com.foo.web.online.util.log.LogMaskingPatternLayout">
                         <pattern>[START] Date: %d{yyyy-MM-dd} | Time: %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} | Level: %-5level | Logger: %logger{5} | Marker: %marker | CIP: %X{clientIp} | UserAgent: %X{userAgent} | Website: %X{website} | SID: %X{sessionId} | RID: %X{requestId} | App: %X{app} | SubApp: %X{subApp} | Page: %X{page} | Device: %X{device} | Browser: %X{browser} | Lang: %X{language} | IPCountry: %X{geoIpCountry} | IPCity: %X{geoIpCity} | ErrCode: %X{errorCode} | Msg: %msg [END] %n</pattern>
                </layout>  
                    </encoder>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>


    <logger name="com.foo" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="SIFT_INFO" />
        <!-- <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> -->
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO" />


</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a root logger like such:

```
<root>
    <level value="ERROR"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="SIFT_INFO"/>
</root>
<logger name="org.mycompany.MyClass">
    <level value="INFO"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: where do you have reference to org.foo.MyClass logger?

Comment: You said you want INFO level on one class only, this is where you put the FQN of your class (I just used an example).

Comment: ok. This is somewhat working. except that it prints the same log twice.

Comment: By twice you mean MyClass prints both INFO and ERROR? That is because ERROR>INFO so INFO level includes all ERRORs.